# Zeroes of irreducible polynomial over splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, proof-explanation, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

I'm reading one theorem in the book called *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* by Gallian, and here's what puzzles me somewhat:

If $f(x) = (x-a)^mg(x) = (x-b)^m\phi(g(x))$ then how does the author deduce that the multiplicity of $b$ is at least $m$? Why not less than $m$ or equal to $m$?

Thank you for clarifying this for me.

[image]

Comment: What's the definition of multiplicity?

Comment: That's how many times a zero of a polynomial appears in the multiset of zeros of the polynomial.

Comment: Yes. So $b$ appears $m$ times as a root already. If $b$ doesn't appear in $\phi(g(x))$ then multiplicity will be exactly $m$, if it appears $n$ times in $\phi(g(x))$, then the multiplicity of $b$ in $f(x)$ would be $m+n$

Comment: @sequence In other words, the multiplicity of $b$ is the largest positive integer $k$ such that there exists a polynomial $h(x)$ with the property that $f(x)=(x-b)^kh(x)$ and $x-b$ does not divide $h(x)$. Does this way of formulating the concept of multiplicity help you?

Answer (score 0):

*From the comments above.*

---

The multiplicity of a root of a polynomial is the number of times the roots appears in the multiset of all roots of the polynomial.

Here, $b$ appears $m$ times as a root of $f(x)$ already. If $b$ appears as a root of $\phi(g(x))$ with multiplicity $n$, then the multiplicity of $b$ in $f(x)$ would be $m + n$. Since $n \geq 0$, we have $m + n \geq m$.

It is useful to view the multiplicity of a root $b$ of a polynomial $f(x)$ to be the largest non-negative integer $k$ such that we can write $f(x) = (x-b)^k h(x)$, where $h(x)$ is a polynomial such that $x-b$ does not divide $h(x)$.

Comment: I don't see where in the proof the irreducible property of $f(x)$ was used. Can you help me look for it? Thanks!

Comment: @TheLastCipher My answer says that if $a$ and $b$ are roots of $f$ such that the isomorphism $\phi \colon E \to E$ maps $a$ to $b$, then the multiplicity of $b$ is at least the multiplicity of $a$. Since $\phi^{-1} \colon E \to E$ maps $b$ to $a$, we also have that the multiplicity of $a$ is at least the multiplicity of $b$. Hence, $a$ and $b$ have the same multiplicity. So far, we have not used the hypothesis that $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: @TheLastCipher The hypothesis that $f$ is irreducible comes up here: if $f$ is irreducible, then for any two roots $a$ and $b$ of $f$, there exists an isomorphism $\phi \colon E \to E$ such that $\phi(a) = b$. If $f$ is not irreducible, then this is not true. So, if $f$ is irreducible, we can say that any two roots of $f$ have the same multiplicity, whereas if $f$ is reducible we can only say that the roots of each irreducible factor of $f$ have the same multiplicity.